# Reading binary values in c

Tags: c, binary

I can read unsigned ints from a binary file but one of the values is printing out negative.

Expected values:

45788331,
281302247,
461354227,
13127,
299215653,
2356985123,

Values printed out:

45788331,
281302247,
461354227,
13127,
299215653,
-1932982173,

The 6th value is printing out as negative but I am reading a list of unsigned ints?

My code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        FILE * fp;
        ssize_t read;
        int r = 0;

        fp = fopen("numbers.bin", "rb");
        if (fp == NULL)
                exit(-1);

        while(fread(&r, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, fp) == 1)
        {
                printf("%d\n", r);
        }

        fclose(fp);
        if (line) free(line);

        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What byte alignment are you using?

Comment: You have `r` declared as signed, not unsigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf("%d\n", r);` prints out a *signed* decimal integer.

You want: `printf("%u\n", r);`

Additionally, `r` is declared as `int` not `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Barmar true, but printf will interpret it the same either way.

Comment: Isn't it undefined behavior to pass a variable of the wrong type for the formatting option?

Comment: @Barmar, I think so, so one shouldn't *rely* on them behaving the same, but in this case the real issue was the format string, and not the type.

Answer (score 1):

Type of `r` is `int`. The range for the 32 bit `int` is `-2147483648`  `= -(2^32)/2`  through `2147483647` = `(2^32)/2 -1` decimal.

`2356985123` is outside the range for the signed `int`. When printing `r` by `printf("%d\n", r);`  r will be presented as `-1937982173`.
`-1937982173` = `2356985123 - 2^32`